# Parse Server - Get Pinned Object using Labels

Tags: parse-platform

I am storing objects in the Local Datastore via Pinning. I can pin objects under a label (e.g. following). If I want to return all of the people that a user is following there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. I can't even find a way to return all pinned objects regardless of their label. Am I missing something?

Here is my code for storing a person object in my Local Datastore:

```
peer.pinWithName( 'Followed' );
```

I can find out if the peer is followed using:

```
const Followed = Parse.Object.extend( 'Peer' );
const query = new Parse.Query( Followed );
query.fromLocalDatastore();
response = await query.get( peer.id );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Querying all objects from local data store

```js
const Followed = Parse.Object.extend('Peer');
const query = new Parse.Query(Followed);
query.fromLocalDatastore();
response = await query.find();
```

Reference: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#querying-the-local-datastore

## Querying an object from pin with name

```js
const Followed = Parse.Object.extend('Peer');
const query = new Parse.Query(Followed);
query.fromPinWithName('Followed');
response = await query.get(peer.id);
```

## Querying all objects from pin with name

```js
const Followed = Parse.Object.extend('Peer');
const query = new Parse.Query(Followed);
query.fromPinWithName('Followed');
response = await query.find();
```

Reference: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.7.0/Parse.Query.html#fromPinWithName